# Getting the function name (__FUNCTION__) for my unit test library's assert function

Tags: c++, unit-testing, c++11, gcc, abi

I am writing a unit test library and I need to log the name of the test function during the assertion, like as follows:

```
struct my_test_case : public unit_test::test {
    void some_test()
    {
        assert_test(false, "test failed.");
    }
};
```

When I run the test case, I want to produce an output like:

```
ASSERTION FAILED (&my_test_case::some_test()): test failed.
```

I know there are some ways to solve this issue:

1. Give `__FUNCTION__` to assert_true()
2. Define a macro like `ASSERT(a, b)` that expands to `assert_true(a, b, __FUNCTION__)`
3. Define a macro like `TEST` to cache the `__FUNCTION__` in the test function

`struct my_test_case : public unit_test::test {
    void some_test()
    {
        TEST
        assert_test(false, "test failed.");
    }
};`

But these are error-prone and ugly solutions. Are there any other solutions to this problem?

Comment: Once i can take some time i will fix the formating...

Comment: You know [Boost Test](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/test/)? It does what you want, and more. Boost is a quasi-standard expansion library for C++.

Comment: In what way is (2) ugly and error prone?  The end user doesn't see anything?  Is it that you don't want to use a macro at all?  In short, please be more specific about what is wrong with your 3 solutions.  In order to have an actual, unique answer, and not a "list of every solution in answers, please", we need better criteria.

Answer (score 0):

something like (2) or a variant thereof will probably be the only choice:

`__FUNCTION__` is not really a function or run time variable, but only exists at compile time; so, no matter what you do, when you need its value at runtime, you will need to locally save the value.

Comment: I agree that this question is not written clearly ,and the title and the explanation do not match at all. I am going to write a better question and let you know.

Comment: Why is `__FUNCTION__` not a run time variable? In this link (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Names.html) it is as if a local static variable `static const char __func__[] = "function-name";`

Comment: I re-phrased my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32880969/getting-a-function-name-func-from-a-class-t-and-a-pointer-to-member-functi/32882070#32882070