# Getting a function name (__func__) from a class T and a pointer to member function void(T::*pmf)()

Tags: c++, function, unit-testing, pointer-to-member

Is it possible to write some `f()` template function that takes a type `T` and a pointer to member function of signature `void(T::*pmf)()` as (template and/or function) arguments and returns a `const char*` that points to the member function's `__func__` variable (or to the mangled function name)?

**EDIT**: I am asked to explain my use-case. I am trying to write a unit-test library (I know there is a [Boost Test](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/test/doc/html/index.html) library for this purpose). **And my aim is not to use any macros at all**:

```
struct my_test_case : public unit_test::test {
    void some_test()
    {
        assert_test(false, "test failed.");
    }
};
```

My test suite runner will call `my_test_case::some_test()` and if its assertion fails, I want it log:

```
ASSERTION FAILED (&my_test_case::some_test()): test failed.
```

I can use `<typeinfo>` to get the name of the class but the pointer-to-member-function is just an offset, which gives no clue to the user about the test function being called.

Comment: No it's not possible. And I don't think any compiler have extensions for this either. Can you perhaps explain your use-case? Why do you need this?

Comment: I explained my use-case in the explanation field, thanks for asking..

Comment: `__func__` is only defined within the function itself. If it's used, it behaves like a local variable with static storage. Otherwise it doesn't exist.

Comment: How about non-standard solutions? Using the `<cxxabi.h>`, for instance? There must be a list of mangled function names in the produced binaries. I see a class named `__pointer_to_member_type_info` so I feel there is some hope...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like what you are trying to achieve, is to get the name of the calling function in `assert_test()`. With gcc you can use 
[`backtace`](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Backtraces.html) to do that. Here is a naive example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <execinfo.h>
#include <cxxabi.h>

namespace unit_test 
{
struct test {};
}

std::string get_my_caller()
{
    std::string caller("???");
    void *bt[3];                             // backtrace
    char **bts;                              // backtrace symbols
    size_t size = sizeof(bt)/sizeof(*bt);
    int ret = -4;

    /* get backtrace symbols */
    size = backtrace(bt, size);
    bts = backtrace_symbols(bt, size);

    if (size >= 3) {
        caller = bts[2];

        /* demangle function name*/
        char *name;
        size_t pos = caller.find('(') + 1;
        size_t len = caller.find('+') - pos;

        name = abi::__cxa_demangle(caller.substr(pos, len).c_str(), NULL, NULL, &ret);

        if (ret == 0)
            caller = name;

        free(name);
    }

    free(bts);

    return caller;
}

void assert_test(bool expression, const std::string& message)
{
    if (!expression)
        std::cout << "ASSERTION FAILED " << get_my_caller() << ": " <<  message << std::endl;
}


struct my_test_case : public unit_test::test 
{
    void some_test()
    {
        assert_test(false, "test failed.");
    }
};

int main() 
{
    my_test_case tc;
    tc.some_test();

    return 0;
}
```

Compiled with:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -rdynamic main.cpp -o main
```

Output:

```
ASSERTION FAILED my_test_case::some_test(): test failed.
```

Note: This is a gcc (linux, ...) solution, which might be difficult to port to other platforms!

Comment: Great! Is it also possible to demangle it using, for instance, cxxabi.h (Do I need to extract `_ZN12my_test_case9some_testEv` from the caller, or is there an API for it, too?)

Comment: I tried your code and the value of the caller was `dist/debug/gnu/test/test() [0x405cd1]` (which is the path to the executable followed by an empty paranthesis)

Comment: @bmm Have you compiled with `-rdynamic`?

Comment: @bmm I have edited my answer, using `abi::__cxa_demangle` to get real function name.

Comment: I tried with `-rdynamic` and it is still `dist/debug/gnu/test/test() [0x405cd1]`. I am using g++-4.7.3, which version is yours?

Comment: @bmm g++ (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04) 4.8.4, are you using `-std=c++11`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91078/discussion-between-bmm-and-sergej).

Comment: It always prints value of caller and name "./Main()". Not working for me.

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR: It is not possible to do this in a reasonably portable way, other than using macros. Using debug symbols is really a hard solution, which will introduce a maintenance and architecture problem in the future, and a bad solution.

The names of functions, in any form, is not guaranteed to be stored in the binary [or anywhere else for that matter]. Static free functions certainly won't have to expose their name to the rest of the world, and there is no real need for virtual member functions to have their names exposed either (except when the vtable is formed in A.c and the member function is in B.c).

It is also entirely permissible for the linker to remove ALL names of functions and variables. Names MAY be used by shared libraries to find functions not present in the binary, but the "ordinal" way can avoid that too, if the system is using that method.

I can't see any other solution than making `assert_test` a macro - and this is actually a GOOD use-case of macros. [Well, you could of course pass `__func__` as a an argument, but that's certainly NOT better than using macros in this limited case].

Something like:

```
#define assert_test(x, y)  do_assert_test(x, y, __func__)
```

and then implment `do_assert_test` to do what your original `assert_test` would do [less the impossible bit of figuring out the name of the function].

If it's unit tests, and you can be sure that you will always do this with debug symbols, you could solve it in a very non-portable way by building with debug symbols and then using the debug interface to find the name of the function you are currently in. The reason I say it's non-portable is that the debug API for a given OS is not standard - Windows does it one way, Linux another, and I'm not sure how it works in MacOS - and to make matters worse, my quick search on the subject seems to indicate that reading debug symbols doesn't have an API as such - there is a debug API that allows you to inspect the current process and figure out where you are, what the registers contain, etc, but not to find out what the name of the function is. So that's definitely a harder solution than "convince whoever needs to be convinced that this is a valid use of a macro".

Comment: @hvd: Added "have to" to explain that "it's not required", rather than "never does".

Comment: Unfortunately it is not a valid answer for the following reasons: (1) it uses macros (2) It is not clear how I can use the debug API in a particular OS (I am working on Linux - GCC) But thanks for detailed explanation.

Comment: @bmm: I have clarified that I don't believe solving this using debug symbols is NOT the right solution, because of the extra burden it puts on you at this point and in the future. Macro IS the right solution for this problem, nothing else is.

Comment: Just wanted to find out if there EXISTS a way to finish the library without using a single macro.. :)

Comment: @bmm: "exists": Yes. "Practically useful": No. I have to head for work now, and will be out until late this evening, but will see if I can find the bits of either GDB or LLDB that does this, and see if I can explain how much code you'll need to write to read the debug symbols, and you'll probably agree after that. But probably not until tomorrow...